# JPA - Get all rows that matches multiple strings

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table UserData with fields such as name, userRole, phonenumber etc. UserRole field can have values like ADMIN, USER, MANAGER, OWNER, VIEWER and many more. I am trying to write a JPA native query that retrieves all the rows where the userRole is ADMIN, USER, MANAGER....

The search criteria is selected from the screen. What can be the JPA query which is similar to the below SQL query.

SELECT * from UserData where userRole = ADMIN OR userRole = USER OR userRole = MANAGER and so on....

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
String selectQuery= "SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.userRole IN :roles"; 
Query query = em.createQuery(selectQuery, UserData.class);

List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "USER", "MANAGER");

query.setParameter("roles", roles);
List<UserData> users = query.getResultList();
```

**Edit:** For Hibernate

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.userRole IN (:roles)");
query.setParameterList("roles", roles);
```

*[It's implementation/version specific - :namedParameter OR (:namedParameter)]*

Comment: If your implementation is Hibernate. I think maybe you should add extra signal: {:roles} or maybe (:roles), just a remind. And I like the way you construct List.

Comment: Hi,
It looks simple. Thanks for the quick answer. Can I use any name as parameter in the place of :roles? Or it has to match with the database table column names?

Comment: @MouliPC No, its just identifier, one with meaningful & appropriate naming convention is fine.

Comment: I was getting an error when using "SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.userRole IN :roles". It got resolved after modifying the query as "SELECT u FROM UserData u WHERE u.userRole IN (:roles)". I am using Hibernate JPA. My apologies since I missed the API information in the question.

It got resolved now. Many thanks for the answers.